# ImagePath changes on display and doesn't find image

Tags: python, django

In my Django Application, I am trying to display an image on a page.
I am querying for the image url in my `views.py`. It prints:`profile_pics/BRICKS_white_small.png`.

The image is located in nightplus/media/profile_pics.

In my index.html I am trying to display this image.

First of all I'm printing the path on the page, which looks promising:

```
    <p>Url: {{picture_url}}</p>
```

prints: Url: profile_pics/BRICKS_white_small.png

Now using:
    `img src="nightplus/{{ picture_url }}" alt="profile_pic"></img`

it doesn't display anything other than the alt attribute.
The Console says: 
**Not Found: /index/nightplus/profile_pics/BRICKS_white_small.png**

I imagine the /index/ part is added for some reason. also "media" is cut off.
Is there a way to change this?